# Testing on iPhone device without SIM card

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I have an iPhone 3G that worked fine for development on iOS 3. I just updated to iOS 4.1.2, and Xcode Organizer tells me `This device is not activated. Please activate it using iTunes`. I've restored twice now.

iTunes tells me to insert a SIM to activate it—however, I don't want to activate it. This iPhone is for development only. The phone itself says "No SIM Card Installed. Insert a valid SIM with no PIN lock to activate iPhone."

How can I get the "please activate" message to go away so that I can use it for development?

**Edit** - I do not have a standard SIM card that I could put in temporarily. All I have is a micro SIM for my iPhone 4.

Comment: check this please [https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3700393?start=0&tstart=0](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3700393?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All you have to do is insert any SIM card, active or not, get the device set up, and then take the SIM card out. It should work fine from there (I use a no-SIM 3G for testing 4.2.1).

Comment: The only other device I have is an iPhone 4, which has a micro SIM. Any other way about it?

Comment: @Greg: can iPhone3G be loaded with iOS 5.x?

Comment: @Greg, does it need to be an AT&T SIM, or can it be from other networks? Considering just purchasing an unactivated SIM.

Comment: @user523234 the highest firmware the 3G can go to is 4.2.1.

Comment: @JamesSkidmore not totally sure, but presumably it would not be carrier-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if the phone is locked with a carrier, you may need a carrier specific SIM. You can buy SIM cards from carriers' stores for a $5-$10. The SIM doesn't have to be associated with an account or phone number. I've definitely had sales associates look at me funny when I try to buy a SIM with no account.